# Cast Errormessage to a string and compare what it contains

Tags: powershell

I want my script to do something if a certain error is thrown from an Invoke-Command. I guess Invoke-Command also introduces more complications. More specifically, I want to do something if I encounter dubious ownership error, and my plan is to do that through matching the error message to a string containing "dubious ownership"

Sorta what my code looks like

```
$scriptBlock = {
     $status = git status
     $status
}

try {
     $result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $example -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch {
     if ($_.ToString() -contains ”big error case”) {
          # I want to get here if error contains ”big error case”
     } else {
          # Do other stuff
     }
}
```

I expect to fall into the if-statement if the error message contains a certain string

Comment: `-contains` is for collection containment tests, not substring searches. You probably want `... -like "*big error case*"`

Comment: [`-contains` / `-notcontains`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains) are _collection operators_: they test if the LHS object is _equal in full_ to at least one element of the RHS collection. They are not to be confused with the  `.Contains()` .NET _method_ for _substring matching_.  While PowerShell has no equivalent operator for _literal_ substring matching, you can use `-like` with _wildcard expressions_ or `-match` with _regular expressions_, both of which are case-_insensitive_ by default.